# How to draw graph with named vertices by adjacency matrix?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the adjacency matrix of graph and I want visualize this graph. I tried:

```
AdjacencyGraph[{v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10},
{{0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
 {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
 {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
 {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0}}]
```

and

```
AdjacencyGraph[
{{0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
 {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
 {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
 {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0}}]
```

Output is:

[image]

How to add names of vertices to graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VertexLabels`does the job.

```
AdjacencyGraph[{
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, 
VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Subscript[v, i], {i, 10}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Similarily to the above:

**Code:**

```
g = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}};

AdjacencyGraph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

**Output:**

[image: Adjacency graph v.1]

Answer (score 1):

Add `VertexLabels -> "Name"` to your first command.

```
AdjacencyGraph[{v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10},
{{0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
 {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
 {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
 {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
 {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
 {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0}},
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
AdjacencyGraph[
    {Labeled[v1, "1"],
     Labeled[v2, "2"],
     Labeled[v3, "3"],
     Labeled[v4, "4"],
     Labeled[v5, "5"],
     Labeled[v6, "6"],
     Labeled[v7, "7"],
     Labeled[v8, "8"],
     Labeled[v9, "9"],
     Labeled[v10, "10"]},
     {{0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
      {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
      {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
      {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
      {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0}}]
```

[image]